# Add LayoutPanel to RootPanel by wrapper

Tags: java, gwt, layout

i have the following problem which seems quite simple but i have spent more than 2 hours and can't solve it.

Look at the following example.

```
public class HeaderForm extends VerticalPanel
{
public HeaderForm()
{
Label label = new Label("Some text here which should be visible");
   this.add(lable);

}
}
```

Here is the entry point

```
public class SomeApp implements EntryPoint
{

public void onModuleLoad()
{

 HeaderForm instance = new HeaderForm();
 RootPanel.get().add(instance);
}
```

.... after this we should see the label text ,right? but nothing...

It's quite weird to me, if i do the same but directly without wrapper class... it works fine.

Please, advice.. so simple but does not work.

Comment: Typo in `HeaderForm` (should read `.add(label)`) - but that shouldn't be the problem... or?

Comment: Yes,that's not the problem, this is just example i have coded manual.

Comment: Looks like it should work to me. Does "Some text here" appear in the DOM?  If you mean `LayoutPanel` instead of `VerticalPanel`, you should use `RootLayoutPanel.get()` instead of `RootPanel.get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is create a new Widget.
Your class HeaderForm should extend Composite, and then you can make a VerticalPanel and add your label to it.
The VerticalPanel is then initialised using initWidget.

```
public class HeaderForm extends Composite
{
 public HeaderForm()
 {
    VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    Label label = new Label("Some text here which should be visible");
    verticalPanel.add(label);
    initWidget(verticalPanel);
 }
}
```

You can now make an instance of your custom widget in your EntryPoint.
Correct me if I made any mistakes.
If you want to add other things to your VerticalPanel you can make a function to return the VerticalPanel or to add other Widgets to it directly.

Hope this solved your problem :)
Cheers!